# Getting Multiple unorganized values from JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript

```
{
 "Exists":true,
 "Id":"c558eedac67244908fc127d028663b96",
 "Type":6,"Fav":false,
 "Shield":false,
 "Tags":" 
    [{\"TagId\":\"T1\",\"TagName\":\"test2\",\"TagType\":1}, 
    {\"TagId\":\"T2\",\"TagName\":\"test1\",\"TagType\":1}]"
}
```

What I am trying to do is, to use `javascript` to get the `TagName` from `Tags` section

When i use `JSON.parse(Obj.Tags);` I get everything under `Tags` section where i only want `TagName`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. You can use the `.map` function.

```
var tagNames = obj.Tags.map(function(x){
    return x.TagName;
});
```

```js
var obj = {
 "Exists":true,
 "Id":"c558eedac67244908fc127d028663b96",
 "Type":6,"Fav":false,
 "Shield":false,
 "Tags": 
    [{"TagId":"T1","TagName":"test2","TagType":1}, 
    {"TagId":"T2","TagName":"test1","TagType":1}]
};

var tagNames = obj.Tags.map(function(x){
 return x.TagName;
})

console.log(tagNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I probably get what your question is.

Would you like your Tags to be only **array of TagName**?

Here's example code:

```js
var Obj = {
 "Exists":true,
 "Id":"c558eedac67244908fc127d028663b96",
 "Type":6,"Fav":false,
 "Shield":false,
 "Tags":"[{\"TagId\":\"T1\",\"TagName\":\"test2\",\"TagType\":1},  {\"TagId\":\"T2\",\"TagName\":\"test1\",\"TagType\":1}]"
}

// Get Tags data to array object

var Tags = JSON.parse(Obj.Tags);

// Get simple array of TagNames

var TagNames = Tags.map(x=>x.TagName);
console.log(TagNames);

// Get array of objects with only TagName key value pair

var TagNamesFormat2 = Tags.map(function(x){
  return {"TagName" : x.TagName}
});

console.log(TagNamesFormat2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` on **Tags**

```js
// Parsed object
var data = {
 "Exists": true,
 "Id":"c558eedac67244908fc127d028663b96",
 "Type":6,
 "Fav":false,
 "Shield":false,
 "Tags": [
    {"TagId":"T1","TagName":"test2","TagType":1}, 
    {"TagId":"T2","TagName":"test1","TagType":1}
 ]
}

console.log(data.Tags.map(tag => tag.TagName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `tags.map(a => a.TagName);`

```js
var myObj = {
             "Exists":true,
             "Id":"c558eedac67244908fc127d028663b96",
             "Type":6,"Fav":false,
             "Shield":false,
             "Tags":"[{\"TagId\":\"T1\",\"TagName\":\"test2\",\"TagType\":1},     {\"TagId\":\"T2\",\"TagName\":\"test1\",\"TagType\":1}]"
            };
            
var tags = JSON.parse(myObj.Tags);
var tagNames = tags.map(a => a.TagName);
console.log(tagNames);
```